# Is there a delta but for division?

Tags: notation

$\Delta x$ represents the difference of the values in $x$:
$$\Delta \{ 1, 2, 4, 7 \} = \{ 2 - 1 , 4 - 2, 7 - 4 \} = \{1, 2, 3 \}$$

Is there a version of this operation, but with division instead of subtraction?

Thanks,
BoxTechy

Comment: what are the properties you hope for with this delta? also note that using a set is wrong, because a set imposes no ordering on your elements. The "correct" way to define the $\Delta$ is by using a sequence. But even with that, *what* property do you want the $\Delta$ to have?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I don't know of a standard name for the idea, but you can define your own if you need it. In your example the result would be $(2/1, 4/2, 7/4)$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you!

Comment: You could use $e^{\Delta\ln x}$. Another possibility is to use the left-shift operator $S^{\star}$ for sequences and clarify in advance that division on sequences means element-wise division. Then you can use $(S^{\star}x)/(x)$.

Comment: You're welcome. The question should have an answer so that others don't think it's worth their further time. You can it yourself, showing us the name you choose.